# Validation form gives an error message but will still submit form

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

My form validation does not work properly. I would put no value in to it and it will give me the message"this field is required" but then it will still add it to my list.

Even when I try to enter a value that is not an email it will give me the right message and it will stop me just once from putting it in my list, but when i push the button again with the same incorrect value it will still add it to my list.

[image]

This is my list:
[image]

And this my code with form and validation:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Cohorts</title>


 </head>
  <body>

 <form id="register-form" class="form-horizontal" name="form" ng-submit="addCohort()">

<div class="form-group">

    <label class="control-label col-xs-3">Name:</label>

<input id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" type="text" ng-model="formCohort.firstname">

<input class = "btn-btn-primary" id="submit-button"  type="submit"   value="Sigin up">
    </div>

    <script>
$("#register-form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

}).validate({
      rules:{
        email:{
          required: true,
          email: true
        }
      }
    });
    console.log("validation functie");

  </script>

  </form>
  </body>
   </html>
```

What am I doing wrong and why does my e.preventdefault not work?

Answer (score 0):

You miss **submitHandler** inside **validation()** method.Inside the **submitHandler** check success or not when success then go otherwise `return false;`.

In example form **name="form"**

```
$("form[name='form']").validate({

    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 3
        }
    },messages: {
        name: {
            required: "Please provide a name",
            minlength: "Your Category must be at least 3 characters long"
        },
        email: "Please enter a valid email address"
    },

    submitHandler: function(form) {

       //Check hear
  
    }
});
```